# Want to add Autoplay setting to Responsive Image Gallery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have added this image gallery http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/ to a site I am working on. Works flawlessly, the only thing is that there is no option to autoplay the slideshow.

http://www.debellephotography.com/debelleslide/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I pieced together bit and pieces here and there and figured out a way to do it, thanks for the help.

```
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
$('.rg-image-nav-next').click()
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
{
timer_is_on=1;
timedCount(1000);
}
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
```

The timeCount function activates the next image every 1 second. The doTimer function prevents the timer from being activated multiple times. The stopCount function allows the pausing of the slideshow.

I then added two buttons to pause and play:

```
<div class="playbutton"><a href="javascript:doTimer();"><img src="images/play.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Play"></a></div>
<div class="pausebutton"><a href="javascript:stopCount();"><img src="images/pause.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Pause"></a></div>
```

You can see it working here: [example with autoplay](http://debellephotography.com/debelleslide/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new button that triggers a setInterval function to loop through the slides. It would look like this:

```
<button onclick="play()">slideshow</button>

function play() {
    setInterval(function() {
       // Do the code that triggers next image
    }, 1000);
}
```

The number 1000 is milliseconds between the function being run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var current=1;
    function autoAdv()
    {
        if(current==-1) return false;

        $('.es-carousel a').eq(current%$('.es-carousel a').length).trigger('click',[true]);    // [true] will be passed as the contentScroll parameter of the click function
        current++;
        $('.rg-image-nav-prev').eq(current%$('.rg-image-nav-prev').length).trigger('click',[true]);    // [true] will be passed as the contentScroll parameter of the click function
        current++;
    }

    // The number of seconds that the slider will auto-advance in:

    var changeEvery = 10;

    var itvl = setInterval(function(){autoAdv()},changeEvery*1000);​
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. As I'm a complete javascript beginner, where would I place this in the .js file (presuming it would go in the gallery.js file.

I pasted it here: 
http://pastebin.me/8d6b367a7ee76be70f944d9b9613572d

Comment: Added it within gallery.js but it actually prevents both thumbnail carousel and gallery from working.

Comment: Nope, but I can't code javascript. Thanks for bearing with me and trying to help though!